# Error in Json syntax

Tags: json

I'm writing a json syntax and when I validate it I keep getting the error,

```
Parse error on line 6:
..."Dublin 1",        {            "produ
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

I can't figure out what the error means.

Here's my code

```
{"invoice":
{"number":"1001",
 "date":"21/02/2010",
 "customer":"Joe Bloggs",
 "address":"Dublin 1",
{"product details":
        [
          "name1":"Table",
          "quantity1":"1",
          "amount1":"250"
         }
         {
          "name2":"Chair",
          "quantity2":"6",
          "amount2":"200"
         }
        ]
}
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is filled with key-value pairs, so I see at least three problems.

1) The "product details" object needs a key. Maybe "product details" was meant to be the key?

2) You are missing the start `{` for the first object in the product details array value.

3) You are missing a comma separating product detail objects.

Here is some valid json that might be what you are intending:

```
{
    "invoice": {
        "number":"1001",
        "date":"21/02/2010",
        "customer":"Joe Bloggs",
        "address":"Dublin 1",
        "product details": [
            {            
                "name1":"Table",
                "quantity1":"1",
                "amount1":"250"
            },
            {
                "name2":"Chair",
                "quantity2":"6",
                "amount2":"200"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Use a JSON validator such as this one to validate your JSON:
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Thanks for that it explains it perfect, I was just going by what my lecturer was telling me to do so I didn't expect it to not validate but thanks again you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest finding a good Json Editor. If you work with C#, Java or other typed languages
consider using libraries that allow you to generate Json. The point is, if you manually assemble JSON, you will have typos, unless you have an eye for details :)

```
{
   "invoice":
      {
         "number":"1001",
         "date":"21/02/2010",
         "customer":"Joe Bloggs",
         "address":"Dublin 1",
         "product details":
         [
            {
               "name1":"Table",
               "quantity1":"1",
               "amount1":"250"
            },
            {
               "name2":"Chair",
               "quantity2":"6",
               "amount2":"200"
            }
        ]
    }
```

}

Comment: While your answer gives the corrected syntax, it does not explain why the original was incorrect, nor how you came up with this answer.